# NSMutableArray into an NSArray Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am a newbie to iOS, I am trying to get an array to work with a Parse.com query

```
userIDS = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// example array that is from a UITableView

for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    [userIDS addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user%i", i]];
}

// Place user1, user2, user3 etc into a format like below so I can query multiple users.

NSArray *names = @[@"user1",
                   @"user2",
                   @"user3"];

[pushQuery whereKey:@"playerName" containedIn:names];
```

I have tried this

```
[pushQuery whereKey:@"playerName" containedIn:userIDS];
```

but that doesn't work.

edit below, below looks for "playerName"s user1, user2, user3 which is what I wanted.

```
userIDS = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// example array that is from a UITableView

for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    [userIDS addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user%i", i]];
}

[pushQuery whereKey:@"playerName" containedIn:userIDS];
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What does "that doesn't work" mean? What is happening, and what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I am not knowledgable about this topic in parse, but they are usually very helpful on the parse help forum.

Comment: I looked through my code again and found a typo that was unrelated, see edit.

Comment: Did you dump both versions of the array and compare them?

Comment: You can use several techniques (eg, `[NSArray arrayWithArray:userIDS]`) to copy a mutable array to a non-mutable one (though I doubt this is necessary).

Comment: Both should work. Please provide a screenshot of your user table in the data browser

Answer (score 0):

Your array must be of `string` values for this to work. Either you must have the `PFObjects` and create an array with their `objectId` or query for the column `playerName`, for this, you must have `string`values of this column in an `NSArray`.

For example, if you don't have the `PFObjects` but know the names you are looking for:

```
NSArray *names = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"PlayerOne", @"PlayerTwo", nil];

    PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"YourClass"];
    [query whereKey:@"playerName" containedIn:names];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
         // Your objects here
    }];
```

Hope it helps.